# How to launch a x64 shell using x86 perl system on windows

Tags: windows, perl, cmd, syswow64

I use perl to call `system start` that I need to specify the cpu number which I want my program to bind to.

When I use x86 perl, it will launch x86 `cmd` to run the start command. This x86 `start` doesn't accept the parameter `0x100000000` as it exceeds 32 bit length. If I use a x64 perl, the whole thing works fine because x64 perl launch x64 `cmd` which accepts `0x100000000`.

So how can I launch a x64 `cmd` to run the `start` command when using a 32-bit perl?

**Details:**

First, I verified that 32bit cmd shell doesn't accept `start /affinity 100000000` while 64bit cmd shell does. In 32bit cmd shell, it throws error `The system cannot accept the START command parameter 100000000.`

Then I tried x64 perl and x86 perl respectively and find x86 perl will get the same error. See commands below.

```
path/to/x64/perl.exe -e "system qq{start /b /wait /affinity 100000000 my.exe}"
path/to/x86/perl.exe -e "system qq{start /b /wait /affinity 100000000 my.exe}"
```

Is there any method to launch a x64 shell using x86 perl to excute start?

Comment: I am not familar with windows, but would [this](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-64bit.html) be of any value? Or using a module like [Win32::Process](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Process)?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thanks for the links, I used Process Explorer to check the cmd image type (32 bit or 64 bit)to be right as my description. I could only use one line perl as I showed so I don't know if win32::Process would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector)
of WOW64 emulator redirects file system paths of `%SystemRoot%\system32` to `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` where `%SystemRoot%` is the a system environment variable which refers to the Windows directory e.g. `C:\Windows`.

So normally, the WOW64 processes (32-bit processes running on 64-bit windows) can not access the `system32` directory.

However, starting with windows Vista, the 32-bit processes can refer to and access the files and folder in the `sysetm32` directory by replacing `system32` with the special alias `SysNative` in the file path.

To launch the x64 cmd shell from a x86 perl instance, you need to explicitly specify the path to the 64-bit cmd.exe by `%SystemRoot%\SysNative\cmd.exe`

```
Path_to_x86_perl\perl -e "system $ENV{SystemRoot}.'\sysnative\cmd.exe /x /d /c start /b /wait /affinity 100000000 my.exe'"
```

Note, however, that this only works on a WOW64 process, So it can not be used as a single one-liner solution for both x86 and x64 versions of perl under Windows. However, you could use the following in a program:

```
use Config qw( %Config );
my $system = $ENV{SystemRoot} . '\\' . ( $Config{ptrsize} == 4 ? 'SysNative' : 'System32' );
```

Comment: This really solved my problem! I don't have to call x86 perl and x64 perl with the same statement so this is enough for me. To make it more clear, what does the option `/x /d /c` mean for cmd.exe?

Comment: @lionel, See `help cmd` or `cmd /?` (both do the same thing)

Answer (score 1):

The following demonstrates the problem simply:

```
>sp5300-x64\perl\bin\perl -e"system 'set'" | perl -ne"print if /^ProgramFiles=/i"
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files

>sp5300-x86\perl\bin\perl -e"system 'set'" | perl -ne"print if /^ProgramFiles=/i"
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)
```

The difference is due to Windows running `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` instead of `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`. This is the result of transparent internal translations, not differences in `PATH`, so being more explicit with the path doesn't help.

```
>sp5300-x86\perl\bin\perl -e"system 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd /x /d /c set'" | perl -ne"print if /^ProgramFiles=/i"
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)
```

The [solution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26681.open-64-bit-command-prompt-in-32-bit-command-prompt-to-execute-64-bit-command-prompt-through-sccm.aspx) is to create a link to `cmd.exe`, and use that instead. This bypasses Windows's shenanigans.

```
>mklink cmd64.exe "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
symbolic link created for cmd64.exe <<===>> C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

>sp5300-x86\perl\bin\perl -e"system 'cmd64 /x /d /c set'" | perl -ne"print if /^ProgramFiles=/i"
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
```